# How do I avoid bad recruiters on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

How can I avoid terrible recruiters on Stack Overflow, especially with the [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) 2.0 release.

Comment: So, could you explain why this question is not a duplicate of the question where you just posted the same answer below?

Comment: @AndrewBarber because in that answer, 3 of 100 recruiters were bad, but here it is only 2 of 100. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I don't think that answers can be duplicates, only questions. That said, this is a very poor question.

Comment: What do you mean by terrible recruiters?

Comment: @JDB definitely true; though duplicate answers can be a possible indicator of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

I do think that it makes sense to have a rating system, or earn a badge for recruiters that are actually helpful. I will say that recruiting firms do have deep pockets and US$6,000 for an annual subscription is not a deterrent. I do think a rating system would be a deterrent, because firms will not pay US$6,000 if they will be kicked off in four months for posting spam.

Here are a few key's to finding the right recruiter, probably only two out of 100 recruiters.

- They share the company’s name before they meet you. Those that do have a strong enough and **real** relationship with their client and do not fear competition.
- They are able to have an intelligent conversation on what you do, and most importantly what you want to do next. Tell them your background, tell them what you want to do, then ask what roles are a fit. If they start jamming HTML/CSS contracts at you when you are clearly a server-side Java developer who prefers full time, hang up on them.
- Ask them questions on how long they worked with their client, the culture of the firm, etc. Avoid recruiters that call all day into companies and get jobs listed, that is a company driven approach, or volume driven. They tend to send eight candidates and see what sticks, a reactive approach. Look for a firm that partners with a firm, sends two candidates and looks to work with passive job seekers, those are the firms you want to work with.